# vue canle loading in axios failed

Tags: vue.js, axios, loading

and there is a question for me.
There's a table like this:

```
<el-table
  v-loading="isLoading"
  :data="householdData"
  border
  style="width: 100%; background: transparent "
  :row-style="tableRowStyle"
  :header-cell-style="{background: '#000099'}">
 ...
</el-table>
```

when a bus event coming, I want the table to be loading and start a axios, when the request over, I want to cancle the loading but failed,

```
mounted() {
let house = this.householdData

bus.$on('data',function (val) {
  this.province = val.province.replace("\"","").replace("\"","")
  this.district = val.district.replace("\"","").replace("\"","")
  this.cell = val.cell.replace("\"","").replace("\"","")
  this.building=val.building.replace("\"","").replace("\"","")
  this.unit=val.unit.replace("\"","").replace("\"","")
  // this.loading=val.loading
  this.isLoading=true
  console.log(this.isLoading)
  this.$axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: address + '/household',
    params: {
      district: this.district,
      province: this.province,
      cell: this.cell,
      building: this.building,
      unit: this.unit
    }
  }).then(res => {
    res.data.data.forEach(item=>{
      house.push(item)
    })
    this.isLoading=false
    console.log(this.isLoading)
  })
})
```

The log shows the isLoading is false but the page is still loading, I'm confused now.
Any help will be grateful.

Comment: `bus.$on('data',function (val) {...}` use arrow function like this `bus.$on('data', (val) => {...}`

Comment: wow, great, it works, thank you bro